# Deflection of a rectangular plate simply supported (transverse load)

Tags: deflection

I am looking for the formula allowing to calculate the deflection of a rectangular plate with a "transverse loading in its center" (maybe the kind of loading will be more clear with this picture : [image]

I already found this formula for the case of a rectangular plate with a concentrated load at center (and I know the one I'm looking for is very close).
https://www.engineersedge.com/material_science/rectangular_plate_concentrated_load_13645.htm

But I can't find the coefficients for my precise case with the load uniformly distributed across the width (as in the first picture)

Thank you

Comment: A quick google search gives https://www.engineersedge.com/calculators/flat-plate-deflection.htm, but what did you find?

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks but I actually want the formula which could match to my case to have an expression of the deflection as a function of E (young modulus).I actually will fix a deflection to find my E and I need to justify the caclulation of this E with a formula (because I do this on a project basis)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of a plate supported on only two opposing sides with loads that are uniform along the width of the plate is identical to that of a beam, so the standard beam deflection equations can be used. The deflection of a beam with a concentrated load at its midspan is

$$\delta = \dfrac{F\ell^3}{48EI}$$

where $F$ is the total concentrated load at midspan, $\ell$ is the beam's span length, $E$ is the material's elastic modulus, and $I$ is its moment of inertia. Considering the plate's cross-section of $w \times t$, we have

$$I = \dfrac{wt^3}{12}$$

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Could you just please explain why here the width w is not taken into account at all? We actually had an answer from our professor who said that we were supposed to find δ=Fw^3/48EI so we don't know If there is not a another way to calculate It with formulas for the rectangulare plates?

Comment: @Gey I think that might've been a typo on your professor's end, getting $w$ and $\ell$ mixed up. And you'll notice that $w$ and $t$ are taken into account: they are the inputs to calculate the moment of inertia, which is then used for the deflection.

Comment: Sorry actually the formula that has been given to us by our professor is δ=Fw^3/48Et with t the thickness and w the width, that's what we don't understand. Maybe using the beams formula here is a kind of simplification and the formula given by our professor is more precise? Or is there really no other way to calculate the deflection than the one you gave us?

Comment: @Gey I can tell you without a doubt that equation is wrong. Just think about it: you have $w$ in the numerator. So the thicker the slab, the greater the deflection? And the length of the span doesn't appear? So a slab a mile long will deflect as much as one an inch long? That makes no sense. Or do [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) on that equation. You have $\delta = Fw^3/48Et$, which in dimensions is $\delta = [F] \cdot [L]^3/48 [F / L^2] \cdot [L] = [L]^4$. Obviously the dimension of deflection is length, not length to the 4th power.

Comment: @Gey now, it may be that simply-supported slabs as in your case (often called "one-way slabs") show some transversal bending moment, but it is insignificant. I very much doubt your teacher is discussing that, since one-way slabs are a standard part of early engineering lessons (from your question, I infer that's your current level) and are taught as "just pretend they're beams". Two-way slabs (where supports exist on adjacent sides) are completely different, but one-way slabs are just very wide beams.

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

Roark’s Formulas for Stress and Strain by WARREN C. YOUNG RICHARD G. BUDYNAS
On pp 435 has a reference to this question.

> A very wide beam of rectangular cross section can be treated as a beam
>   if E is replaced by $\frac{E}{1-\nu^2}$ and $I$ by $t^3/12$ (see Sec. 8.11). It can also
>   be treated as a plate with two opposite edges free as shown in Figs.
>   8.16 and 11.2. For details see Ref. 88.

If you don't have access to it I suppose I can take picture of the page and give it to you. Because another conditions apply too.